# javascript jspdf blob freeze browser, web workers?

Tags: javascript, blob, web-worker, jspdf

I'm trying to embed client side input images in a PDF which is generated using `jspdf` library. I got some questions:

Using jdpdf library I've tried the various options:
`var doc =  jsPDF();`

`var bloburl = window.createObjectURL(doc.output("blob")) // freeze the browser in mobile devices
window.open(bloburl); // or iframe.src=bloburl;`

The problem is - the UI for few seconds in an average mobile device, so maybe web worker will help somehow? 
Also when setting blob url to src of something, mobile devices prompt a download, while desktop view them in browser. (I prefer both ways to open PDF in browser, as with any other PDF I open in browser).

another method:

```
var b64 = doc.output("datauristring");
window.open(b64); // create a giant string and freeze the browser, but both desktop and mobile will view the PDF in browser, which I prefer.
```

**TL;DR**
- Can I Use web workers to prevent browser freeze when generating large blob urls?
- How can I avoid mobile browsers to prompt download when setting bloburl to src of something? (desktop browsers don't prompt a download).

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Your questions are far too broad and there are too many in one post.

Comment: :(  I could edit and maybe reduce some, or create a new post.. though  akk here revolve around blobs and blob url

Comment: I would ask each question in individual posts as required by SO. Also make a more descriptive title.

Comment: What is purpose of creating blob url?

Comment: Updated post and title

Comment: The purpose is to set the blob url in an src of iframe or window.open, so the user can preview the pdf.

Comment: Have you tried using `data URI` of `.pdf`? Desktop browsers use some form of a plugin to render `.pdf` documents in browser

Comment: yes, this is the second method I tried, which creates a giant base64 string, which can also be set in an src of an element, but also freezes a mobile browser. But the positive in this way -  it does not prompt a download in a mobile browser. I'd prefer using the blob obviously - less memory.

Comment: Have you tried alternatively rendering image using `<canvas>` element? Why use `.pdf` to display an image?

Comment: Because I needed the PDF, the client needs to download a pdf (one document, which contains multiple images). Anyway, the post is old, at the time I gave up on trying to create PDF in client side JS. I ended up with server-side solution. For today, there is simply no good way (i.e, cross platform, and at least with a minimal user experience) to generate PDFs using client side JS.